# spring-mvc,hibernate ошибка при отправке данных с формы. ошибка 500

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, glassfish

```
        type Exception report

        messageInternal Server Error

        descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

        exception

        org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

        root cause

        java.lang.NullPointerException

        note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
        GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 





    в логах была написана вот это   
    (не могу понять почему NullPointerException)


    [2016-02-12T00:37:38.275+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1455226658275] [levelValue: 900] [[
      StandardWrapperValve[mvc-dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.springapp.service.ModelService.getEntMod(ModelService.java:27)
        at com.springapp.mvc.MoiController.getMod(MoiController.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


[![та самая ошибка][1]][1]



[![библиотека.может версии не те?][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36HAG.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGwMm.jpg

HELLO CONTROLLER просто вывожу hello.jsp
a в hello.jsp две формы которых обрабатывает MoiController.java и должен добавить данные в базу.

HelloController.java

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}

MoiController.java


@Controller
public class MoiController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addmodel",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addMod(HttpServletRequest request){

        ModelService service = new ModelService();
        EntityModel model = new EntityModel();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");

        model.setName(name);
        model.setLastName(lastName);

        service.addMod(model);

        return "res";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getmodel",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getMod(HttpServletRequest request,Model m){

        ModelService service = new ModelService();
        EntityModel model1 = null;

        Long l = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));

        model1 = service.getEntMod(l);

        m.addAttribute("name",model1.getName());
        m.addAttribute("lastName",model1.getLastName());


        return "res2";

    }


}



EntityModel.java


@Entity(name = "model")
public class EntityModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String  lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



}

ModelService.java


@Repository
public class ModelService {
   @Autowired
   private HibernateTemplate template;



    @Transactional
     public void addMod(EntityModel entityModel){
         template.save(entityModel);
     }



    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public EntityModel getEntMod(Long id){

       EntityModel entityModel = (EntityModel) template.get("EntityModel", id);

        return entityModel;
    }
}

POM.xml


  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>


app-context.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
              <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pn"/>
              <property name="username" value="root"/>
              <property name="password" value="tuha"/>
       </bean>


       <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
           <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
       </bean>




       <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
             <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
              <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springapp.model"/>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                     <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                     </props>
              </property>



       </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.service"/>



</beans>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Над сервисом используйте аннотацию @Service, а в месте создания экземпляра сервиса используй аннотацию @Autowired .

Answer (score 2):

У вас в написано  в каком месте возникает ошибка:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.springapp.service.ModelService.getEntMod(ModelService.java:27)
```

Это здесь:

```
EntityModel entityModel = (EntityModel) template.get("EntityModel", id);
```

Т.е. `HibernateTemplate` у вас не заинжектился. Вы вызвале метод `get()` на нулевом объекте, отсюда NPE.

Не заижектился он потому, что в контроллере вы создали сервис вручную - в обход DI контейнера.

```
ModelService service = new ModelService();
```

Не создавайте сервис вручную, используйте `@Autowired`, чтобы заинжектить его в контроллер.

Comment: спасибо.сработало.записал в базу,только с чтением проблемы